# C#, How to access object methods in a generic method

Tags: c#, object, generics, generic-list

I have 2 data classes that have a method isSenior().

```
public class Staff : Member, IComparable<Staff>, IEquatable<Staff>
{
    public string Occupation { get; set; }
    public override bool isSenior()
    {
        var today = DateTime.Today;
        var age = today.Year - Birthday.Year;

        if (age > 65)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And

```
public class Player : Member, IComparable<Player>, IEquatable<Player>
{
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Club { get; set; }
    public bool Invited { get; set; }
    public bool Captain { get; set; }
    public override bool isSenior()
    {
        var today = DateTime.Today;
        var age = today.Year - Birthday.Year;

        if (age > 30)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I want to use this method in another generic method that returns a list of all senior people, for example

```
List<Player> allSeniorPlayers = TaskUtils.findSeniorMembers<Player>(allPlayers)
```

Is it somehow possible to call the isSenior() method like this:

```
    public List<T> findSeniorMembers<T>(List<T> allMembers)
    {
        List<T> seniorMembers = new List<T>();
        foreach (T member in allMembers)
        {
            if(member.isSenior())
            {
                seniorMembers.Add(member);
            }
        }
        return seniorMembers;
    }
```

The error is on member.isSenior(). Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: You haven't shown where `isSenior` is declared, but assuming it's in `Member`, I suspect you just need to constraint `T`: `public List<T> findSeniorMembers<T>(List<T> allMembers) where T : Member`. More notes: 1) that method body can just be `allMembers.Where(member => member.IsSenior()).ToList();` 2) Now would be a good time to fix your names to follow .NET naming conventions - methods should start with a capital letter; 3) `IsSenior` sounds like it would normally be a property, not a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `isSenior` is defined in `Member`, you just need to restrict `T` to `Member` or its subtypes:

```
public List<T> findSeniorMembers<T>(List<T> allMembers) where T : Member
```

Documentation:

- [Constraints on type parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)